# trouble restoring dump, $libdir/postgis-2.1 missing

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a university project in which I continue a project of last year.
I never used those tool and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERREUR:  n'a pas pu accéder au fichier « $libdir/postgis-2.1 » : No such file or directory
```

I download PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGIS 2.2.1 with stack builder on windows, and try to restore first a "Dump_Dabatase_Structure.sql" and then "Dump_Dabatase_Data.sql" but got the error when trying to restore the structure

EDIT: I deleted postgis with the uninstaller because your command said me i didnt have the postgis extension and used your installer but now im getting:

```
ERREUR: n'a pas pu charger la bibliothèque « C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/postgis-2.1.dll » : unknown error 127
********** Erreur ********** 
ERREUR: n'a pas pu charger la bibliothèque « C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/postgis-2.1.dll » : unknown error 127 
État SQL :XX000
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying you haven't previously used PostgreSQL/PostGIS in your work, but you are trying to use a previous person's work by restoring their database? Can you also post the command you use for the restore, or are you simply executing the `.sql` script?

Comment: what i mean is that in my university in the 3rd years, you have a group project on some new technologie. My project is based on some other group work from last yeats where i need to add function to an android app that manage a grocery list and have a function to find shop nearby  with a server to use REST api. I have nerver worked with a database , android, or REST api. I didnt used a command for now beside double cliking the .sql dum file and load it on pgAdmin where the error appear

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to restore a database created with an old version of PostGIS (2.1) to a newer version (2.2).

I would recommend trying to downgrade your PostGis version to `2.1.x` by using the following command in your database, assuming you have no data loaded in it (Please backup your current DB if you do!)

```
DROP EXTENSION postgis;
DROP EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

And then running the `postgis-bundle-pg94x64-setup-2.1.8-1.exe`  installer (if your Windows is 64-bit) from [here](http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg94/archive/)

Comment: i deleted postgis with the uninstaller because your command said me i didnt have the postgis extension and used your installer but now im getting:

    ERREUR:  n'a pas pu charger la bibliothèque « C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/postgis-2.1.dll » : unknown error 127
    ********** Erreur **********
    
    ERREUR: n'a pas pu charger la bibliothèque « C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/postgis-2.1.dll » : unknown error 127
    État SQL :XX000

Comment: Hi your comment got cut off. Feel free to edit your original question to add more details

Comment: Hi @Serk, are you using Windows 7? What command did you run to get the error you mentioned? Have you tried running the `CREATE EXTENSION ...` commands in pgadmin? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685525/postgresql-error-could-not-load-library-postgis-2-1-dll)

Comment: Sorry, i edited my original question.
What i did step by step: launching the windows 10 the terminal with 'cmd', then 'psql -U postgres' and type the 'YOUR COMMENT' but it gave the error, so i used the uninstaller on C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5, and reinstalled the 2.1 version you linked me and then opened the dump.sql wit pgadmin and press run where it gave me the error

Comment: After you ran the installer did you run `CREATE EXTENSION ` in pgadmin? Can you see if there's the `postgis-2.1.dll` in `/PostgreSQL/9.4/` folder?